# Can't import pytagcloud in jupyter notebook but I installed the library using pip

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytagcloud

I can't import **pytagcloud in jupyter notebook**. How do I solve this problem? I searched some tutorials and also installed other packages required but still doesn't work?

Do you have any suggestion?

Here is my code. Thanks.

```
import pytagcloud as pytagcloud

import codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from konlpy.tag import Twitter
# utf-16 인코딩으로 파일을 열고 글자를 출력하기 --- (※1)
samsung = codecs.open("samsung.txt", encoding="utf-8")
line = samsung.readlines()
twitter = Twitter()
word_dic = {}
for line in line:
     malist = twitter.pos(line)
     for word in malist:
         if word[1] == "Noun": #  명사 확인하기 --- (※3)
            if not (word[0] in word_dic):
                word_dic[word[0]] = 0
            word_dic[word[0]] += 1 # 카운트하기
# 많이 사용된 명사 출력하기 --- (※4)
keys = sorted(word_dic.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
for word, count in keys[:40]:
     print("{0}({1}) ".format(word, count), end="")
print()

keys

import pytagcloud
taglist = pytagcloud.make_tags(keys, maxsize = 80)
taglist

pytagcloud.create_tag_image(taglist, 'wordcolud.jpg', size = (900,600), fontname = 'Nobile', rectangular = False)

%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud as wordcloud

wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords = stopwords)
wordcloud = wordcloud.generate_from_keys(keys)

wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(keys)

draw_wordcloud_from_rss(keys)
```

[cmd:pytagcloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mues3.png)

[cmd:pygame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HjQO.png)

[cmd:simplejson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNsoh.png)

[jupyter notebook: pytagcloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwTEA.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post relevant code, error messages and printouts not as images but rather inline in your question. Thanks!

Comment: How are you running jupyter? Is it the same python installation as pip? If there are multiple python installations you may be installing the libraries in the wrong one. See [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, thank you for reminding me:) I edited my post with code.

Comment: First, I open Anaconda prompt and then I type "jupyter notebook" on it.

Answer (score 0):

I asked one of my colleagues and she gave the answer!

So the problem was simple. I installed all those libraries in 'cmd'

but I had to install them in "Anaconda prompt".

So, if you have same problem as mine, try this.

```
# Anaconda prompt

pip install pygame
pip install -U pytagcloud
pip install simplejson
jupyter notebook.

# Import.
```

I succeeded to import pygame, pytagcloud and simplejson libraries.
Yet, I have still errors in my code of the post above and there is more libraries to install(konply..etc). error is everywhere!

Anyway, I hope this helps someone.